# Combining List<Base> with List<Derived>

Tags: c#

How can I do the follwing:

```
public class BaseItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedItem : BaseItem
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<BaseItem> baseList = new List<BaseItem>();
        List<DerivedItem> derivedList = new List<DerivedItem>();
        baseList.Add(new BaseItem() { Title = "tester"});
        derivedList.Add(new DerivedItem() { Title = "derivedTester", Description = "The Description" });

        baseList.AddRange(derivedList);
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Henk

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In C# 3.0/.NET 3.5, `IEnumerable<T>` is not covariant. However, this would probably work OK in C# 4.0/.NET 4.0.

For now, you could (in .NET 3.5) use:

```
baseList.AddRange(derivedList.Cast<BaseItem>());
```

(note that you'll need "`using System.Linq;`" at the top of the file)

Before that... probably easiest just to loop:

```
foreach(BaseItem item in derivedList) {baseList.Add(item);}
```

Comment: I want to send the combined list throug a webservice to a client (using jQuery), now the webservice method passes back IEnumarable, but then I never got the description property. Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using .net 3.5, try adding the items of the derivedList like this:

```
baseList.AddRange(derivedList.Cast<BaseItem>());
```